# Pass C# Method Reference to Native C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am working on creating a C++/CLI wrapper so that I can access a C# library in native C++. I've got about 60% of the wrapper finished, but I'm hitting a snag. The SDK for the C# library gives the method inputs/outputs as:

```
public bool GetNumBytesReceived(ref ulong numBytesReceived)
```

I'm at a loss as to how to grab numBytesReceived and pass it on to native C++. I feel like this question must have been asked before on SO, but I'm only seeing things that try to go the other way (from native C++ to C#). I've gotten the following to compile for my C++/CLI wrapper, but it gives a NullReferenceException when I access it from native C++:

```
public: bool NumBytesReceived(unsigned long long& numBytesReceived) {
    return _CSManagedClass->GetNumBytesReceived(numBytesReceived);
}
```

I've also also been able to get it to compile without the input reference (&). Based on my debugging, the issue appears to be in the C++/CLI wrapper, I just don't know where.

Any help is appreciated, and I apologize if this has been asked already. I am still relatively green in the C family of languages.

Comment: Your syntax is correct: `void Test(long long &value) { System::Int64::TryParse("42", value); }` works without issues. Either `_CSManagedClass == nullptr` or you have a bug inside of `GetNumBytesReceived`.

Comment: Thanks for the help yet again Lucas. I felt like I checked and quadruple checked this, and it seemed right. I'll have to contact the people that made the C# library and see if there is an issue in the method.